# wrong date() output java

Tags: java, date

Let me start by saying that I know Date() is deprecated, I've looked at the other questions on here where everybody states that.

I'm doing an assignment which involves using Java Swing to develop a GUI, part of the GUI is a date of birth field with three JComboBox's for day, month and year respectively.

I've got the code to get the selected item from each three and then make the date:

```
Integer day = (Integer) dobDay.getSelectedItem();
Integer month = (Integer) dobMonth.getSelectedItem();
Integer year = (Integer) dobYear.getSelectedItem();

Date dob = new Date(day, month, year);
```

however the correct date is not what is output, I get things like

> Date of Birth: Sat Oct 11 00:00:00 GMT 1919

If I select 14, 4 & 1900 from the combo boxes.

I can't figure out how to correct this, and I'm getting confused because I have a `controllerConsole` class to test my classes and inputs in which Date() works,

```
int dobD = 14;
int dobM = 4;
int dobY = 1990;

Employee e = new Employee("Gethin", 'M', new Date(dobD, dobM, dobY), "02",
    new Date(9, 9, 2011));
```

Even though Date() is deprecated, from this I get the output I want: 14 April 1990 (I have a monthAsString constructor in my Date class to convert the month number to month name).

I would really appreciate any help with this! 
I've seen the Calendar class mentioned as an answer to this since Date() is deprecated but my assignment asks for use to use the Date() class, and I'm not sure what they would think if I chose to use Calendar instead.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the constructor you're calling? Read it **carefully**. (You've got the order wrong *and* the numbers aren't adjusted for the base values that `Date` uses.)

Comment: In 2018 you want `LocalDate.of(1990, Month.APRIL, 14)`. It will object if you put the arguments in any order except the correct order. And there is no need to adjust any of them in any way. Generally forget about the `Date` class, it is outdated, and use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
new Date(1990, 3, 14)
```

returns:

```
Sat Apr 14 00:00:00 CEST 1990
```

which is what you expect. Everything is explained in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(int,%20int,%20int)) (notice the order of parameters and valid values):

> public Date(int year, int month, int date)
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> - year - the year minus 1900.
> - month - the month between 0-11.
> - date - the day of the month between 1-31.

And BTW:

> Let me start by saying that I know Date() is deprecated

No, it's not. It's poorly designed (mutable, confusing `toString()`, doesn't really represent... [date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date)), but not deprecated. Only the constructor you are (incorrectly) using is deprecated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new Date(90, 3, 14)`? I recall (no JVM here) that `Date` did automatically add `1900` to the year (and the javadoc supports me)

Comment: How is Date useless? It's bad designed, but it's far from being useless, IMO (unless you use joda-time, of course).

Comment: @JBNizet: yes, it was a hidden reference to [tag:joda-time] ;-). It's a just poor, mutable wrapper around `long`, thus pretty much useless. But I'll change my answer, don't want to be controversial.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use deprecated methods.**

It is `Date(year, month, day)`, not the other way around.

Adding to that, the year value is automatically added 1900 (so, to get 1999, the `year` value must be 99) and you get it.

**Don't use deprecated methods.**

Comment: Thanks, I've done that using 

Date dob = new Date(year+1900, month - 1, day);

but now I get
Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 5790

for 1/1/1990

Comment: fixed it by taking away 1900 instead of adding it, which I'm guessing is what you meant in the beginning, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The [Date constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) expects year, month and day, in this order. You pass day, month and year.

Comment: so how come it works in my controller class where I pass it day, month and year?

Answer (score 0):

If you can give string values for month then you can use SimpleDateFormat to format a string to date. Using concatenation you can get the date in this format "25-Nov-2012". check this link for more information http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html